# How to get n(th) element's top in angular's ng-repeat?

Tags: element, render, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to get the .top() of an item inside ng-repeat.
How do I get access to the top value after it has been rendered?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$index points to current item index in a ng-repeat. Now let say your ng-repeat is something like -

```
div(ng-if="feeds.length>0" ng-repeat="post in feeds")
```

then to add a div to the required element you can use -

```
div(ng-if="feeds.length>0" ng-repeat="post in feeds")
   div.bottomEl(ng-if="(feeds.length - $index)==3") &nbsp;
```

So, now even if you dynamically change the feeds array the bottomEl automatically shifts to the calculated item index. 
After which you can easily determine if window has been scrolled till bottomEl by using waypoints like this -

```
$('.bottomEl').waypoint(function() {
  //trigger code here
});
```

Be sure to initialize waypoint library

```
<script src="/path/to/waypoints.min.js"></script>
```